# Dropdown Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Estou tentando selecionar um o dropdown com selenium C#, mas como podemos ver no HTML abaixo não existe um "ID" ou "Name", abaixo o código de como estou fazendo, poderiam me ajudar?

```
<select ng-model="vm.activeWhatsapp.channel_id" 
                    ng-options="channel.id as channel.display_name group by channel.sector.name for channel in vm.whatsappChannels" 
                    class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched">
                    <option value="?" selected="selected">
                    </option>
                    <optgroup label="Itaú Cartões Ativo">
                    <option label="Liderança - Itaú Cartões Ativo" value="number:1325">Liderança - Itaú Cartões Ativo</option>
                    </optgroup>
                    </select>




    //Selecting a drop down control
    public static  void SelectDropDown(IWebDriver driver, string element, string value, string elementtype)
    {

        if (elementtype == "Id")
            new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id(element))).SelectByText(value);
        if (elementtype == "Name")
            new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Name(element))).SelectByText(value);
        if (elementtype == "Class")
            new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(element))).SelectByValue(value);

SeleniumSetMethods.SelectDropDown(drive, ".ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-empty.ng-touched", "1325", "Class");
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode acessar via classPath. Utilize o `F12` e siga essa estrutura aqui:

```
//*[@<elemento desejado, pode ser id, name etc>='nome']<caminho ex:/tbody/tr> //*[contains(text(),'<texto que se encontra na tag>')]
```

Caso tenha dúvidas me fale, comigo da sempre certo hehe.

Answer (score -1):

Olha sei bem como é isso, não ter um ID ou Name nos prejudica muito, geralmente eu uso Xpath do Selenium para pegar o valor ele vai direto na tag, veja se o exemplo abaixo lhe ajuda:

```
SelectElement Selec_Event = new SelectElement(itauPednO9.FindElement(By.Xpath("//*[@id="navbar"]/ul/li[3]/a")));
                Selec_Event.SelectByText(value);
```

Veja se adianta

Atte!

Answer (score -1):

É possível encontrar um elemento por várias maneiras no Selenium. Particularmente quando não há um ID, ou NAME, ou quando o ID ou o NAME são duplicados, eu prefiro usar o CSS Selector, pois acho mais "entendivel" que o Xpath.

Mas tanto para obter o CSS quanto o Xpath há um recurso interessante no Chrome.
Ao apertar `F12`, inspecione o elemento que deseja obter os dados, aperte com o Botão Direito do Mouse, vá em `Copy` e selecione o desejado ( CSS Selector ou XPath )